# Changing div content from image to any color

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to do this effect where the background changes on hover. Just like in this gif, I want to have an div with image as background, an overlay (another div) with opacity 0.5s with any color, and then on hover to make the background all white. I tried to change the opacity of overlay (0.0) but it didn't change nothing and hover didn't worked properly.

I couldn't find anything that would help me. Can you guys link me something or at least just explain the logic behind this.

In the gif below you can see what I am trying to achieve.
Thank you for your time!

[image]

UPDATE: Added code.

```css
.qm-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 35%;
  /* height: 300px; */
  /* margin: 0px 60px; */
  position: relative;
  /* padding: 20px 20px; */
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.qm-container img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.qm-overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* background: #225470; */
  background: rgb(5, 69, 151);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.qm-container h6 {
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}

.qm-container p {
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}

.qm-container:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: all .6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="qm-container">
                        <img src="/img/Qmupdated.png" alt="">
                        <div class="qm-overlay"></div>
                        <div class="quality-management">    
                            <h6>1. Quality Management Systems according to ISO 9000 2015</h6>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                                sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                                porro
                                quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

Here's my actual problem:

[image]

I want the image to not be visible on hover.

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far.

Comment: Have you code something? Because nobody will code for you. If you have tried to code please post here maybe in a working snippet and explain where you are stucked.

Comment: I've written code but didn't worked so I just deleted to don't mess it out. All I am asking is the logic or a link to something where I can find something useful. I am not asking for code. I'll edit the post now and add some code which hopefully may be useful.

Comment: I suppose, you need to remove the background-image on hover and set the background to white color.
1. Wrapper block with  background-image, relative position
2. inner text block with absolute position.
3. Wrapper block hover, remove bg image and set to white bg
Or simply add white bg to inner text block on wrapper hover, but don't forget to set the inner text block to 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approx. sample how to do it. Then you can add transition effect.

```css
.wrapper {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300);
position: relative;
}

.inner-text {
color: black;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper:hover .inner-text {
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inner-text">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also have an image and here's where it gets tricky. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to remove the image on hover (hover in wrapper). You can check the code, I'll also send another gif of my actual problem.

Comment: I fixed it! Just changed the opacity of **.qm-container:hover .qm-overlay** from 0 to 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `:hover` to your code with the background color.

```css
.qm-container:hover {
  background: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

I hope this is what you mean.

https://codepen.io/farawyne/pen/jOVrXZw?editors=1100

```css
.post-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.post-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.post-card:hover {
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-card">
  <div class="post-text">Example</div>
</div>
```